# Java Jpa OneToMany relation problems

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa

I have next entities.Everytime i load filmManager from db the amount of sessions is wrong.

```
@Table(name = "FILM_MANAGERS")
@Entity
public class FilmManager { 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FILM_ID",updatable = false,insertable = false)
    private Film film;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "filmManager")
private List(FilmSession) sessions;

other fields...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "FILMS")
public class Film {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "film")
    private FilmManager filmManager;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "film")
    private Ticket ticket;

other fields...
}

@Table(name = "TICKETS")
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "FILM_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Film film;
}

@Table(name = "FILM_SESSIONS")
@Entity
public class FilmSession {
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FILM_MANAGER_ID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private FilmManager filmManager;
}

    @GetMapping("/films/{filmId}")
    public String getFilm(ModelMap modelMap, @PathVariable("filmId") String filmId) {
        FilmManager filmManager = filmManagerService.getFilm(Long.parseLong(filmId));
        modelMap.addAttribute("filmManager", filmManager);
        modelMap.addAttribute("screenshots", resourceExtractor.getScreenShots(filmManager));
        modelMap.addAttribute("sessions", filmManager.getSessions().stream().map((e) -> e.getSessionTime()).collect(joining(",")));
        System.out.println("amount of sessions: " + filmManager.getSessions().stream().count());
        return "filmPage";
    }
amount of sessions: 11
```

That last SOUT outputs 11 sessions when on the screen you can see i have only one.[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJd0Y.png)

i found out that everytime i insert new ticket for the film the amount of sessions on view page grows.So basicaly sessions are multiplying with tickets instead of 1 it loads 11.
here is screen of my tickets table [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kZTl.png)

Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: `private List(FilmSession) sessions;` does this even compile? 1 film only has 1 ticket?

Comment: Yes,it should be List<FilmSession> sessions;i am noob here,first time posting question

Comment: i found the problem.i had OneToOne relation with Ticket in Film class,changed it to OneToMany

Comment: I think you messed up your cardinalities/model somewhat... (there are 11 tickets with film_id == 1) ;)